# Looping through a two-dimensional array in a asp.net MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, model, type-2-dimension

My problem is as follows:
I'm making a ranking board for my team.  I've managed to get the data out of the database and I put it into a two-dimensional array.  I sent it as model data to the view.
Now I don't know how to loop through the two-dimensional array.

Normally it would be something like this:

```
For Each record in Model
...
Next
```

How do you loop through two dimensions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just use two loops?

```
  For i = 0 To Model.ArrayProperty.GetUpperBound(0)
     For j = 0 To Model.ArrayProperty(i).GetUpperBound(0)
        doWhatever( Model.ArrayProperty(i)(j) )
     Next
  Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought it was that easy.
Quick response btw ;)